# CSS media query min-width & max-width not working

Tags: css, media-queries

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/codepenuserpro/pen/ExQrEbo

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1068px) and (max-width: 1380px)
{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Why isn't the div changing background color even when I resize the browser window to between 1068 - 1380px?

Answer (score 1):

## Media Query Syntax

A media query consists of a media type and it can contain one or more expressions, which resolve to either true or false.

If it resolves to true, the css code inside of it is applied.

```
@media not|only mediatype and (expressions) {
  <stylesheet>
}
```

You must select the element- **`div`** in this case, inside the media query as of the following.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1068px) and (max-width: 1380px) {
  div {
    background-color:blue;
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1068px) and (max-width: 1380px) {
  div {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't select the div in the second approach.

You may want to have this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1068px) and (max-width: 1380px) {
    div {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the selector(div) inside media query.
try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1068px) and (max-width: 1380px){
  div{
    background-color:blue;
  }
}
```